# IO Error using etree in python (anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to run the following code using Spyder in Anaconda 4.1.12 (Python 2.7):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("path/file")
root = tree.getroot()
for report in root.iter('Name'):
    print(report)
    tag = report.find('Name2')
    print(tag)
    for group in report.iter('Name3'):
        for tx in group:
            print('FOUND')
            print(tx)
            tx.append(tag)
with open("path/output",'w') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(root))
```

For some reason I'm getting one of two errors.

1) `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:` I've double checked that the path is correct and to my knowledge I have to include ('w') to write the file.

2) The program will halt half way through and I have to reset the console

Does anything look incorrect?

Comment: Does the file exist? If not, using `'w+'` will create the file. If you remove the ET parsing and manipulating, can you open and write to the file?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser No this would be a new output file. I tried with w+ as well and ran into the same issue (with w replaced by w+ of course).

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly! `'w+'` is for reading and writing, `'w'` will also create the file if it doesn't exist. Do you still get an error if you use a file that does exist?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser That seems to just cause the program to hang. No output to file and no signs of completion (e.g. printing FOUND).

Comment: Does it hang when the file is opened, when the file is written to, or when `ET.tostring(root)` is called?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Sorry for the delay, it appears to be during the `with open` process.